# What does this "subst" invocation do?

Tags: batch-file, subst

I would like to know what this command does in a batch script:

```
subst Q: /D  1>nul  2>nul
```

Comment: Create a file nul with contents:

Invalid parameter - Q:

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a DOS command (not bash).

`subst` [substitutes a folder for a drive letter](http://www.computerhope.com/substhlp.htm) or substitutes one drive letter for another

The /D deletes (actually unmounts) a virtual (previously substituted) drive. So your command basically removes the virtual drive Q:

The `1>nul` and `2>nul` just get rid of the output (ie sends the standard output and standard error output to the nul device).

Comment: And there's no bash equivalent to this command, as UNIX doesn't have drive letters.

Comment: Yep. Gave me some traumatic flashbacks there for a moment, too. My edit to his/her tags and title is queued for review.

Answer (score 0):

The subst command you are talking about is a DOS command, not bash.

What it does, is that it unmounts the virtual drive Q:, and the  1 > nul 2 > nul basically means that all output from the command is discarded.