# if else loop in a .bat script

Tags: batch-file

I figured out a way to write a if condition in .bat script :

```
if %sample==1(
echo "successful"
)
```

but how do I add else condition to it?

Comment: http://linuxconfig.org/Bash_scripting_Tutorial#9-1-simple-bash-ifelse-statement

Comment: Isnt it a shell syntax? I tried it in bash and it gave me an error.

Comment: *It's not anything near valid shell code...*

Comment: Based on this and your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11660000/bash-interpretaion-for-the-command-subst-q-d-1nul-2nul/11660071#11660071), you seem to be confusing DOS *batch* scripts for Unix *bash* scripts.

Comment: yes I am. Please could you show me an example of if else in .bat file

Comment: Here's some [basic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983508/can-i-have-an-if-block-in-dos-batch-file) [documentation](http://www.computerhope.com/if.htm). You might consider changing the tags on these two questions (ie remove the [bash] tag and add [dos] and [batch] tags).

Answer (score 2):

Quite simply.

```
    if %sample==1(
    echo "successful"
    ) else (
    echo "unsuccessful"
    )
```

By the way, if you're comparing strings, you'll need the `%` on both sides (`%sample%`).

Answer (score 0):

```
if %sample==1(
echo "successful"
) ELSE (
echo "failed"
)
```